# Stuck on Recursion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Having a problem understanding the solution to this question:

> The
>   == operator compares objects by identity. But sometimes, you would prefer to compare the values of their actual properties.
>
> Write a function, deepEqual, that takes two values and returns true
>   only if they are the same value or are objects with the same
>   properties whose values are also equal when compared with a recursive
>   call to deepEqual.
>
> To find out whether to compare two things by identity (use the ===
>   operator for that) or by looking at their properties, you can use the
>   typeof operator. If it produces "object" for both values, you should
>   do a deep comparison. But you have to take one silly exception into
>   account: by a historical accident, typeof null also produces "object".

Here is the solution:

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {   
  if (a === b) return true;
     if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
      b == null || typeof b != "object")
          return false;

  var propsInA = 0, propsInB = 0;

  for (var prop in a)
    propsInA += 1;

  for (var prop in b) {
    propsInB += 1;
    if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
      return false;   }

  return propsInA == propsInB; 
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}; 
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj)); // → true 
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2})); // → false     
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2})); // → true
```

Particularly having problems with what is happening in the 2nd for loop and what we're returning after it. The question is from Eloquent Javascript Chapter 4.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

In second `for` loop:

```
// #1
propsInB += 1;
```

counts objects properties

```
// #2
!(prop in a)
```

checks whether object `a` has same property as `b` has

```
// #3
!deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop])
```

checks if property value for both objects has same values (deepEqual is used here because it might be comparing pair of another objects too)

if #2 or #3 fails it returns false immediately, but if it won't happen (which means that `a` has all `b`'s properties) it finally checks if the number of all properties in both objects are equal. If they are - objects are same instances.

**EDIT**

I rewrite whole code so it will be more readable for you.
Notice that i changed `prop` to both `prop_a` and `prop_b` for each for loop

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {

    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a == null || typeof a != "object" || b == null || typeof b != "object") {
        return false;
    }

    var propsInA = 0;
    var propsInB = 0;

    for (var prop_a in a) {
        propsInA += 1;
    }

    for (var prop_b in b) {
        propsInB += 1;
        if (!(prop_b in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop_b], b[prop_b])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return propsInA == propsInB;

}
```

Comment: how is !(prop in a) comparing whether object a has same property as b has?

Comment: @FrancescoGallo because you are iterating over `b` props, then checking if `a` has one

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to how the checking is happening or what line of code is doing the checking. Why isn't it set up like (prop in a == prop in b) ? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @FrancescoGallo `for (var prop in b) {` iterates over every property of `b` assinging it to variable `prop`. Then you compare each of these `prop` (from `b`) to an `a` object. I'd make an edit to my answer so you can see what's happening clearly.